# Execute migration files dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How can we execute a mignation file dynamically from the source code. Means we want to execute a migration file from an action of a controller. How can we do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue was that we do not know the names of migration files. I do it with the following code

```
ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate("vendor/plugins/#{self.id.to_s}/lib/db/migrate/", nil)
Package::Rake.call('db:schema:dump')
```

And the Rake class have the following method

```
def call(task, options={})
   options[:rails_env] = Rails.env
   args = options.map { |n,v| "#{n.to_s.upcase}='#{v}"}
   system "rake #{task} #{args.join(' ')} --trace >> #{Rails.root}/log/rake.log &"
end
```

Hope this will help some body with similar problems.

Answer (score 2):

This is assuming the migration is static and in your db/migrate directory when the app server starts:

You could add the migrations directory to your autoload path in config/application.rb, and then require the migration file to be run inside your controller (or in a config initializer):

application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/db/migrate)
```

your_controller.rb

```
require '20101209102033_some_migration_file'
#....
SomeMigrationFile.up
```

I would be interested to know what the use case is here.  Seems pretty wild!

Comment: Use case: want to test impact of indexes. So I want to run a script that has a subclass of ActiveRecord::Migration, a subclass of ActiveRecord::Base (that links to a copy of a table I am interested in); then run migration up, test performance over copy of table; undo migration; done. I then modify script to create different set of indexes and check again.

Comment: I'd be interested to get a glimpse of this research that you have done!